# PHP static keyword and create_function issues

Tags: php

I have recently encountered some rather funny issues with PHP. I am trying to create a closure in PHP and assign it to a static variable so it only needs to be defined once...

```
    static $hasParent = create_function( '$category, $parent_id', <<<'FUNC'
        ...code...
FUNC
);
```

However it tells me `unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'`.
Is this a PHP "feature" (read bug), or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note**:
>
> Static variables may be declared as seen in the examples above. Trying
>   to assign values to these variables which are the result of
>   expressions will cause a parse error.

ref: http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

---

so, **not ok**:

```
function foo() {
  static $bar = function () {
    echo 'bar';
  };

  echo 'foo', $bar();
}

foo();
```

**ok**:

```
function foo() {
  static $bar = null;
  if ($bar === null) {
    $bar = function () {
      echo 'bar';
    };
  }

  echo 'foo', $bar();
}

foo();
```

Comment: Thanks Yoshi, the bit that was getting me was I was trying to assign what is essentially an expression. Thanks again!